# Kali Linux bluetooth bluez shows only device's MAC address but not name?

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am using `Kali Linux 2020.2`, `bluez` installed for Bluetooth. When I search devices I only see the MAC address, but not the name of the devices. I found this GitHub issue, but it was closed without a solution:

```
https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/944
```

Here is the image[image: bluetooth-device-mac-address]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

https://superuser.com/questions/778660/changing-bluetooth-device-name

I've not tested it myself. Please, let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: ithank you for your answer. I tried it but it is an old post. files do not have specified options. However it is good that i saw the main.config for bluetooth but could not find any related setting